# how can i add fontawesome to javascript element?

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

Good evening guys. I am preparing a todo app. I added delete button but I want to add icon from fontawesome to delete button. Where exactly do i need to add <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> ? I would be glad if you help me

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="newtask">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title..." />
        <button onclick="newElement()">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Script-->
    <script>
      var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName('LI');
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
        var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
        var txt = document.createTextNode('\u00D7');
        span.className = 'close';
        span.appendChild(txt);
        myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
      }

      var close = document.getElementsByClassName('close');
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
        close[i].onclick = function () {
          var div = this.parentElement;
          div.style.display = 'none';
        };
      }

      function newElement() {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        var inputValue = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
        var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
        li.appendChild(t);
        if (inputValue === '') {
          alert('You must write something!');
        } else {
          document.getElementById('newtask').appendChild(li);
        }
        document.getElementById('myInput').value = '';

        var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
        var txt = document.createTextNode('\u00D7');
        span.className = 'close';
        span.appendChild(txt);
        li.appendChild(span);

        for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
          close[i].onclick = function () {
            var div = this.parentElement;
            div.style.display = 'none';
          };
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to highlight here is,

First, the code piece to delete a list item is not deleting the actual item, but just hiding it from rendered `HTML` and that's wrong. You should remove that element completely from the document. The below code is not deleting in actuality.

> ```
> close[i].onclick = function() {
>    var div = this.parentElement;
>    div.style.display = 'none';
> };
> ```

Secondly, answering your query about adding icons using `<i>` tag. If you are adding this dynamically it should be done the same way you did with the `<span>` tag. You have to do createElement and append that element to its parent. You can link the fontawesome in your HTML document's `<head>` part. Here is the generic CDN link.

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
> ```

For an updated version of the above link, you can check their official [website](https://fontawesome.com/).